# Why use a passphrase for RSA key?

Tags: rsa, memory, passphrase

Today I generated my first key pair, so my knowledge here is - so to speak  - very limited.

On client side I am using Windows and to log in I use PuTTY and I used PuTTYGen to create the keys.

Here (https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen) they say:

> If you leave the passphrase fields blank, the key will be saved
>   unencrypted. You should not do this without good reason; if you do,
>   your private key file on disk will be all an attacker needs to gain
>   access to any machine configured to accept that key. If you want to be
>   able to passwordless log in without having to type a passphrase every
>   time, you should consider using Pageant so that your decrypted key is
>   only held in memory rather than on disk.

But here I am failing to see why I should even use RSA rather than regular password authentication when I need to use the passphrase. If I do a passphrase I still need to type in a password when logging in.

On a side I would ask a question about this part:

> Pageant so that your decrypted key is only held in memory rather than on disk

Does it really protect anything? I don't know how to read things from memory but isn't it a fairly common thing to do for hackers? To read/replace bits in memory?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [Is using a public-key for logging in to SSH any better than saving a password](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3887/16235)

Comment: RSA is intended to improve security, not convenience

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not *need* a passphrase for your RSA key. But if your key gets compromised (for example, because you carry the key on a thumb drive and you lose it), an attacker could immediately access the assets the key is protecting.

Using a strong password will give you more time to change keys in case of a key compromise.

Related question on Superuser:

- [Do I need to have a passphrase for my SSH RSA key?](https://superuser.com/questions/261361/do-i-need-to-have-a-passphrase-for-my-ssh-rsa-key)

Comment: The other advantage of using a password protected key instead of a password alone is that even if an attacker learns your password (perhaps through a keylogger), it's useless to him unless he also steals the key.